# Given the list {12 30 40 0 47}, how many swaps will occur during the outer loop execution (i = 3)?

Tags: java, sorting, time-complexity, swap

So I have a class where we are taught how to code in Java. We were learning about sorting algorithms like Bubble, Merge, Insertion or Quick sorts and their time complexities. In a quiz, I got this question. The answer to this question was 3. Why is that the answer? (btw the question was just that. No program or description was provided).

Comment: This question with this wording makes zero sense. Either there was actually more context, a different wording or something else is missing.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but I swear to bloody god that this is all that was provided. In most questions we literally had to assume what kind of algorithm is being used.

Answer (score 1):

There is your list
{12 30 40 0 47}

you only need 3 swaps to sort it :

{ 12 30 0 40 47 }
You swap the 0 with 40

{12 0 30 40 47 }
You swap the 0 with 30

{0 12 30 40 47 }
and finally you swap 0 with 12

that's why the answer is 3, tell me if you didn't understand !

Comment: Thanks! but how do you not get confused into thinking that if this was a bubble sort, the algorithm would swap 0 2 times and mistakenly choosing 2 as the answer? When you have professors this tricky, how do you deal with them like that?

Comment: Because in your question, your professor precise "swap", so you cannot use like bubble sort or anything else, you can only use swap !

Comment: Oh I see. So how should I use this info _during the outer loop execution (i = 3)_ in my favor so I don't get confused again? What is that _i = 3_ actually there for?

Comment: I think the i=3 should represent :
for(int i =0; i < 3 ; i++)